# Sub View's frame is updating after presenting the view Controller

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout, size-classes

I am using a view controller's view as sub view in my view controller. All is well till I don't present a new view controller from the visible view controller.
After dismissing the view controller frames of my view controller (added as sub view) changed. All the view controller view is made with the auto layouts.

I have tried to update frame of sub view's in the viewDidLayoutSubvieww.

Please let me know how to solve this problem thanks.

EDIT:

I am presenting view controller like this from the sub view

```
// Show report abuse view 
let vcReportAbuse = ReportAbuseViewController(nibName:"ReportAbuseViewController‌​", bundle: nil) 
    vcReportAbuse.target = self 
    vcReportAbuse.info[ParamName.AbusedUserID.rawValue] = userProfileModal?.uId 
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vcReportAbuse) // 
    nav.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve
self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in })
```

Comment: How are you presenting the viewController?

Comment: @RashwanL
I am presenting view controller like this from the sub view


        // Show report abuse view
        let vcReportAbuse = ReportAbuseViewController(nibName:"ReportAbuseViewController", bundle: nil)
        vcReportAbuse.target = self
        vcReportAbuse.info[ParamName.AbusedUserID.rawValue] = userProfileModal?.uId
        
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vcReportAbuse)
        // nav.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve
        self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
            
        })

Comment: Try to make your presented view controller alpha transparent and look what happens with underneath subviews using slow animation toggle in Xcode simulator. And/or if you already work in Xcode 8, you can also examine your view controller layout using magic Debug View Hieararchy Button, while app is running in simulator. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

Answer (score 0):

Set your view frame in `viewDidLoad` method...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all
This issue is resolved. I just updated the view controller object from the new view controller is presenting. Firstly I was presenting it from the subview.